# Add NodeJS (a-color-picker) -> Uncaught Exception: ReferenceError HTML Element is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my `html`.file i have the **following code**:

```
<div class="picker"
     acp-color="#EFE9E7"
     acp-palette="PALETTE_MATERIAL_CHROME"
     acp-palette-editable> 
</div>
```

My `js` file looks like **this**:

```
    const AColorPicker = require('a-color-picker')
AColorPicker.from('.picker')
    .on('change', (picker, color) => {

    })
    .on('coloradd', (picker, color) => {
      // color added: color
      // modified palette: picker.palette
    })
    .on('colorremove', (picker, color) => {
      // color removed: color
      // modified palette: picker.palette
    });
```

When I start this, nothing is shown and I get the **ReferenceError**, but I have installed the node, and I find it with autocomplete in my files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mistake backend and frontend code `require` are using in the backend code or in forentend if you are using appropriate tools like `browserify or requirejs`. If you want run this code and see results, the easiest way is add `script` tag with color picker:

1.index.html file

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/a-color-picker@1.1.8/dist/acolorpicker.js"></script>
   <script src="./app.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="picker"
    acp-color="#EFE9E7"
    acp-palette="PALETTE_MATERIAL_CHROME"
    acp-palette-editable> 
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

2.app.js (in the same folder as index.html)

```
AColorPicker.from('.picker')
.on('change', (picker, color) => {

})
.on('coloradd', (picker, color) => {
   //color added: color
   //modified palette: picker.palette
})
.on('colorremove', (picker, color) => {
    //color removed: color
    //modified palette: picker.palette
});
```

Here a fiddle for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/c5za83pn/

Comment: @ManuelRiedl have you found another explanation to this problem?